# How to nest structures in Go

Tags: go, data-structures, struct

I'm working on structs, methods, and interfaces in Go, and am writing some code to test the concepts. I'm stuck on the following concept in an example I'm creating - some amplifiers have preamp tubes and power tubes. I thought I could define them in the amp struct using a generic tube struct, but of course it doesn't work the way I have it written, and when I research nested structs, they don't seem to be the applicable concept. How do I structure this so that "amp" has "preamptubes" and "powertubes", and those are each type "tube"?

```
type tube struct {
    model  string
    number int8
}

type amp struct {
    name         string
    model        string
    manufacturer string
    color        string
    knobs        int8
    switches     int8
    jacks        int8
    preamptubes  tube
    powertubes   tube
    ouputpower   int8
    fxloop       bool
}
```

**Edit: Update:**
I should have including the error I was getting in the question. I rewrote the package this morning, and the preamptubes and powertubes types now work as expected. I suspect the problem was with how I was instantiating them in the main function. The following now works. This isn't production code, just an exercise to practice concepts. Thanks for helping me take a fresh look at it.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type tube struct {
    model  string
    number int8
}

type amp struct {
    name         string
    model        string
    manufacturer string
    color        string
    knobs        int8
    switches     int8
    jacks        int8
    preamptubes  tube
    powertubes   tube
    ouputpower   int8
    fxloop       bool
}

func main() {
    a := amp{
        name:         "MegaAmp",
        model:        "MA9000",
        manufacturer: "Amps R Us",
        color:        "blonde",
        knobs:        9,
        switches:     5,
        jacks:        6,
        preamptubes: tube{
            model:  "12AX7",
            number: 3},
        powertubes: tube{
            model:  "6V6",
            number: 4},
        fxloop: true}

    fmt.Println(a)
    fmt.Println(a.preamptubes.model)
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the types you've included in your question? What problem are you experiencing?

Comment: Looks to me that `amp.preamptubes` and `amp.powertubes` are both correctly declared as type `tube`

Comment: "it doesn't work the way I have it written" - how so? What you've described seems to be exactly what your code defines, so it's not clear what the problem is.

Comment: When I was working on the package last night, I was getting an error, which I should have included in the question. I recreated the package this morning, and it does appear the powertubes and preamptubes were both correctly declared. I suspect the problem was with how I instantiated an amp type in the main function.

Answer (score 2):

I may be misunderstanding, but are you asking for a nested slice of structs? To accomplish this, simply use `[]tube`:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type tube struct {
    model  string
    number int8
}

type amp struct {
    name         string
    model        string
    manufacturer string
    color        string
    knobs        int8
    switches     int8
    jacks        int8
    preamptubes  []tube
    powertubes   []tube
    ouputpower   int8
    fxloop       bool
}

func main() {
    v := amp{
        name:        "da amp",
        preamptubes: []tube{{model: "A"}},
        powertubes:  []tube{{model: "B"}},
    }

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", v)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/bPGHuEO40D0

Just a shot in the dark here, but you might also be running into `import` issues if your values exist in separate packages. Changing the first letter to an uppercase (ie, `Tube`, and `AMP` [see https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#initialisms)) to access structs from different packages.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what exactly are you trying to achieve (what's the context / large picture here?), but consider this:

You can add another flag to the tube to designate its type, then have an array of types

```
type tubekind int

const (
    preamptube tubekind = iota
    powertube
)

type tube struct {
    model  string
    number int8
    kind tubekind
}

type amp struct {
    tubes        []tube
    // ... other fields
}
```

You can create a tube this way:

```
tube{"model", 1, powertube}
tube{"model2", 2, preamptube}
```